# How to manage Db migrations(seeding) for the Dynamo DB in .Net

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We are planning to have a AWS dynamo db to store the reference data which will be used by our .net microservice. We would like to seed this table over time. So we would need some db migration utility like DBUp(sql server) to do that.

I would like to check, if there is an utility or package managing these for dynamo db in .net ior is there any standard way of doing this. please advise.

Comment: **seed this table over time**? Like scripts to populate it? Pretty sure there's a version of the AWS Db Migration Assistant for Dynamo.

Comment: Please install this package from Nuget

Install-Package AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2

and more help https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NET.01.html

Comment: @JeremyThompson Yes with seeding I mean here is adding new records to the existing table.